# WordPressで別のデータベースへ接続

Tags: mysql, aws, wordpress

ワードプレス本体はEC2のローカルｍySQLで接続していますが、アクセスカウンターとアンケートのプログラムだけAWS RDSに接続したいのです。

RDSを作成してエンドポイントのURLをEC2側のtest.phpにPDO記述したんですが、Nginx503エラー（タイムアウト）が返されます。

ワードプレスディレクトリに入っている場合、別途PDO接続はできないのでしょうか？
RDSインスタンスは利用可能状態で、VPC,セキュリティグループ等は接続可能です、パブリックIP可

また、PHP構文の記述に間違いありません。

```php
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=mydbinstance.abcdefghijkl.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;port=3306;dbname=mydb';
$username = 'sa';
$password = 'mypassword';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
?>
```

こちらを参考に作りました。
http://blog.be-style.jpn.com/article/73397659.html
;pdo.so
などのPHP設定も正しく設定されています。

Comment: 解決するには、phpの返すエラーが必要だと考えます。上記のphpをwordpress に載せずに直接実行数ろt、繋がるのでしょうか？

Comment: echoだけすると表示されるのでPHPは実行されます。PDO接続ができません。エラーは503以外わかりません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
AWS VPCのセキュリティグループでインバウンドのHTTP 80のアクセス許可をMyIPにしていたのが原因でした。